# How to update element style in Dash callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I am using dash cytoscape to draw a tree plot. I want to be able to update the style of a terminal node using a Dash callback. I can get the callback to run and output the updated style, but the figure does not update, I'm guessing this is because of the diffing method used. I have tried returning the stylesheet as part of the callback as well as this was suggested in another post. Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how I can get the style to update?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change html.Img() style in callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541663/how-to-change-html-img-style-in-callback)

Answer (score -1):

You can add an item 'type' to your element 'data' key and then add a selector for this type on your stylesheet. For example :

```
          style_sheet = {
                            'selector': '[type = "your_type"]',
                            'style': {
                                'background-color': '#9cd0e2',
                                'shape': 'star',                                    
                                "text-wrap": "wrap",
                                "text-max-width": 80
                            }
                        }

          elements = [{'data':{'id':'your_id', 'label':'your_label', 'type':'your_type'}]
```