# how to change html.Img() style in callback?

Tags: plotly-dash

I am using html.Img(src='image.png',style={'height':'300px', 'width':'100%') to add image.

I'd like to change image size in callback for different images, one thing I can think of is to change style of image to change image size in callback. I don't know how to change style of Img component in callback. Thanks for help.

here is the code in callback

define html.Img() component first

```
    html_img_well = html.Img(id = 'html-img', src = '',
                                style={'height':'300px', 'width':'100%'})
```

in cabllback

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("html-img", 'src'),
    ],
```

def change_dts_sql_plot():

```
image_well='assets/'+wellname+'_image.PNG'
```

return seismic_image_well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

`Output("html-img", 'style'),`

and then use a callback, the same one even if you wanted (multiple outputs) to change the style. You could also put the `Img` component inside a `div`, and then update the `div`'s `children` property with a new `html.Img` each time, allowing you to set all the properties.